# Setting 3440x1440 resolution makes screen turn off in sway

Tags: archlinux, wayland

I am trying to increase the refresh rate of my monitor. I first get my monitor information using this command:

```
swaymsg -t get_outputs
```

which returns these informations

```
Output DP-3 'Unknown U34G2G4R3 0x0000094A' (focused)
  Current mode: 3440x1440 @ 59.973 Hz
  Position: 0,0
  Scale factor: 1.000000
  Scale filter: nearest
  Subpixel hinting: unknown
  Transform: normal
  Workspace: 1
  Max render time: off
  Adaptive sync: disabled
  Available modes:
    3440x1440 @ 59.973 Hz
    3440x1440 @ 144.001 Hz
    3440x1440 @ 120.000 Hz
    3440x1440 @ 99.982 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 143.945 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 120.000 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 119.880 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 59.976 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 60.000 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 59.940 Hz
    2560x1080 @ 50.000 Hz
    1720x1440 @ 59.936 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 60.000 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 59.940 Hz
    1920x1080 @ 50.000 Hz
    1680x1050 @ 59.954 Hz
    1280x1024 @ 75.025 Hz
    1280x1024 @ 60.020 Hz
```

From this I understand that my current refresh rate is 60 and that I can go up to 144.

I try to set my resolution + refresh rate using this command (I tried the command also without the refresh rate, resulting in the same behavior where the monitor turns off)

```
swaymsg output DP-3 mode 3440x1440@144Hz position 0 0
```

As soon as this is entered, the monitor turns off displaying no input source. I then have to run `swaymsg reload` to return to my previous settings.

Here is what my specs look like in case that is usefull:

`````
                   -`                    jaro@workstation
                  .o+`                   ----------------
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux
                `+oooo:                  Kernel: 5.18.1-arch1-1
               `+oooooo:                 Uptime: 56m
               -+oooooo+:                Packages: 397 (pacman)
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Shell: zsh 5.9
            `/++++/+++++++:              Resolution: 3440x1440
           `/++++++++++++++:             WM: sway
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           Terminal: kitty
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X (12) @ 3.7GHz [37.2°C]
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Memory: 2138MiB / 32071MiB (6%)
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Disk (/): 7.2G / 255G (3%)
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
 `++:.                           `-/+/
 .`                                 `/
`````

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of test and research, I decided to try testing on X11 in order to find more ressources. I ended up discovering that the `nouveau` drivers were responsible for the screen blackout. After downloading the proprietary drivers for my graphics card, I could set my resolution and refresh rate of 144Hz perfectly. Sadly, Wayland does not support proprietary drivers... I guess I need to keep X11 as my main display server on this desktop.